# "Laravel" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: laravel, composer, laravel-6

Uso Windows 10, y estoy en la carpeta que Laragon guarda sus proyectos (C:\laragon\www). Desde el terminal digito esta línea para crear un nuevo proyecto:

```
laravel new auth
```

Pero me devuelve el texto del título de la pregunta.

Corrí un *composer update*, reinicié Laragon, luego reinicié Windows, pero no funcionó. Después intenté crear el proyecto a la manera de siempre...

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel –-prefer-dist NombreDeProyecto
```

Se creó con normalidad. Luego quise ejecutar esta línea para montar la autenticación...

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Pero me respondió:

```
Command "make:auth" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?
    make:channel
    make:command
    make:controller
    [...]
```

En todo caso no he podido avanzar.

Qué puedo hacer? Gracias!

Comment: En el PATH... Eso pensé. Pero qué variable es?

Comment: En el segundo caso, entiendo que *artisan* está disponible, pero no así el comando. Puedes listar los comandos disponibles de artisan con: `php artisan list`

Comment: Usando `php artisan list` en otro proyecto de esa misma carpeta, sí aparece _make:auth_ como disponible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primer error.**

Cuando te dice que *Laravel no se reconoció como un comando interno o externo* se debe a que no existe en las variables del sistema.

Lo que debes hacer es entrar a la siguiente ruta:

```
C:\Users\tuUsuario\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

En esta ruta esta el ejecutable del instalador de Laravel, posterior debes ir a:

- Inicio
- Equipo
- Porpiedades
- Configuración avanzada del sistema
- Variables de entorno

En el área **variables del sistema** busca la que se llama **PATH** y ahí:

- Elijes nueva (me parece ya que no uso windows 10)
- Pegas toda la ruta y das click en guardar
- Cierra la terminal, abre una nueva y prueba el comando de nuevo

**SEGUNDO ERROR**

[Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/authentication) ha quitado del *core* el comando `make:auth`, si lo deseas continuar usando; entonces deberás hacer lo siguiente:

Instalar el paquete por separado con este comando:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Ahora ejecuta el comando `php artisan` el cual te devuelve la lista completa de comandos donde verás que existe uno nuevo llamado:

```
ui:auth
```

Que dice:

> `Scaffolding basic login and registration views and routes`

Una vez ejecutado el comando anterior entonces tendrás disponible la creación de las vistas de registro y login tradicionales

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 28/11/2019**

Desde la versión **`2.3.X`**<sup>1</sup> del instalador de laravel; puedes *bajar* una copia nueva de un proyecto de Laravel con el scaffolding básico de autenticación de este modo:

```
laravel new tu-proyecto --auth
```

**¿Qué pasa si no me reconoce dicho comando?**

Comprueba la versión de tu instalador de Laravel con el siguiente comando:

```
laravel -V
```

Si el resultado del comando anterior te arroja una versión inferior a la mencionada; entonces actualizala de este modo:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

**Referencias**

- [Comando `ui:auth`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/authentication)
- [Instalación del package `laravel ui`](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/ui)
- [--auth Laravel](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1196556840575938560)

Comment: Lo hice todo, pero no funcionó. Después accedí manualmente a esa ruta (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin), pero dentro de Composer, solamente hay tres archivos y no hay carpetas. No existe Vendor, y por ende tampoco vendor/bin

Comment: Funcionó. Muchas gracias @Aprendiz. Solo que no entiendo por qué la primera instalación no movió predeterminadamente el archivo Laravel a esa carpeta, y no sé en dónde estaba antes. Cuando corrí `composer global require laravel/installer` de inmediato dijo que movería todo a AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor...

Answer (score 0):

Espero que con la siguiente línea se solucione:

```
composer gobal require laravel/installer
```