# ¿Por qué no me aparece la carpeta de componentes al instalar Vuejs en Laravel 6.3?

Tags: laravel, composer, vuejs, laravel-6

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con Laravel y estoy siguiendo un tutorial completo. Resulta que hago la instalación de Laravel con Composer pero no me agrega por defecto la carpeta

> /resources/js/**components**

.

> Quisiera saber como puedo solucionar esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La versión actual de Laravel para instalar es la 6, entonces te pregunto seguro que si instalaste la 5.8?

Comment: Si ciertamente la versión instalada es 6.3

Comment: Revisa si lo que propongo como solución para el segundo error en está pregunta te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291628/laravel-no-se-reconoce-como-un-comando-interno-o-externo-programa-o-archivo-p/291631#291631

Comment: Ya logré instalar la versión 5.8 y ciertamente ahora si aparece el directorio components. Muchas gracias

Comment: creo que a lo que se refería Aprendiz es a que en la versión 6.x debes instalar `laravel/ui` con `composer require laravel/ui`, luego podrás instalar el andamiaje frontend usando el comando `php artisan ui vue`. Digo por si no querías bajar la versión

Comment: Así es @porloscerros